# Extract URL from HTML/Text but if URL only shows partial like "/secondpage.html"?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, web-services, web

I'm trying to extract a URL from a HTML snippet in string format.

I've been using regex to retrieve the part between href=" and ". However, I noticed that in some cases href links to pages within the website without containing the root URL. For example, a snippet can be like:

```
<div class="textcontent" id="desc">
<br>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/confirm/url/aHR0cHLy9yYZy50bw%3D%3D/"  class="ajaxLink">link</a><br>
```

Instead of the more usual:

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
```

Where I can just use this regex to narrow down my results:

```
/href\n*=\n*".*?"/
```

I looked around StackOverflow, and saw a few posts about this (extracting URLs from html/text), and saw a mention of using an external library like <strike>JSoup. This is for a Chrome Extension, so I'm hoping to keep it lightweight (if that might be an issue).</strike> *(JSoup is a Java library not JS).*

Are there any good solutions for this "partial URL" problem? Would it be best to just check and append to the URL if root is missing, or would using external library like JSoup be more advised?

Comment: JSoup is a Java library, not a Javascript Library.

Comment: Did not notice that -- thank you for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the direction you took by using a regex, the best approach could be to parse the extracted URL in order to detect one of the following three kinds of URL possibilities:

1. ***Protocol://FQDN/Document***
2. ***/DOCUMENT/***
3. ***DOCUMENT/***

The first case points to an absolute document, the second points to an absolute document but omitting the protocol and the FQDN, and the third points to a relative document.

For the second and third cases you need to know the ommitted information in order to build a complete URL. Assuming you know the URL of the original HTML snippet code, the problem here is to detect what kind of possibility are you facing for each href. If you don't know the original URL, you are in a lack of information, meaning that you can't complete the HREF.